# Best approach to reset a variable after 1 hour

Tags: c#, timer

In my API I receive requests with IDs, the caller in case of certain types of errors (i.e. http 500) that could occur when receiving the response sends back the same request with the same ID, we realized that we have n identical processes on the DB , this is because we record the response on Mongo but the caller does not always receive it, to overcome this I was asked to check if the id is new flow proceed with the normal flow otherwise send the response already recorded.

While doing some tests they realized that they had requests with the same ID but with different bodies and responses and so as not to have to check all the fields of the request they asked me to implement this further verification.

> Insert a control on delta time (1 hour) with previous call, i.e.:
>
> - time 10:00 request id=1 – normal flow
> - time 10:59 request id=1 – retrieve response
> - time 11:01 request id=1 – reports error “idrequest already used”

Is it feasible to create a model with request id and status that resets every hour, to monitor the various requests?
I would insert this timer into the API controller by passing the variable into the request method

**UPDATE**
Update for the flow
Send request:

- id not present? -> new flow
- present id:

  1. received less than 1h ago -> return saved response
  2. received more than 1h ago -> return duplicate request id error

I would think of saving myself in the Mongo document in addition to the date which already has the time, except that the previous one with only the date? In this case I should always give a duplication error

Comment: this strongly suggests an XY problem.

Comment: How is that an **ID** if it is _not unique_? So, you actually _need_ a second factor (perhaps a hash of the body?).

Comment: _"Is it feasible to create a model with request id and status that resets every hour, to monitor the various requests?"_ in MongoDB you can [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-data-from-collections-by-setting-ttl)

Comment: This sound more like a weird workaround then a solution. Is there a problem making something called Id really unique?

Comment: On our side, no, the caller generates the ID, but I fear that whoever wrote the tests first used the same IDs to do the tests (the customer uses the same test environment that we also use so I don't know if it's a potential problem let it happen again)

Comment: ^^ I am seeing 2 issues here: One is that you have been tasked with what is basically "Response Caching". But your Key is not really suitable for that kind of caching, for whatever reason. So, that is the second issue: how to come up with a suitable key. Because I am guessing changing any contract concerning that key will end in a dumpster fire ...